# Image file keeps getting deleted

Tags: 7, media, files

I'm using the [Image Title](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_title) module with Drupal 7. I can successfully upload an image to be used as a title, however the images keep getting deleted. It looks like the problem is similar to [this question on SO](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/149483/image-getting-delete-away-by-the-cronjob-later-in-drupal-7-using-theme-settings).

Oddly, I've been using [image_title](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_title) for several years but never encountered this problem until now. And the module is basically abandoned, so there are no recent changes to it that would have changed the behavior - so has there been some change in Drupal itself that could explain this?

As a workaround I went into mysql and did `update file_managed set status = 1` for the image file in question, is that likely to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I would forget about using that module and simply have a field that contains the desired image, and change your node template file to display that image in place of the title.

It is important to have a text title (even if it is not displayed) because it is used in search engine listings.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably what I should do.